# Webview webapp advertising, how to do it once right and get it cross-platform?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ads, multiplatform

**Introduction**

Made some HML5/CSS3/Javascript games that can be run on almost any device with a proper browser (responsive). It also runs on Android 2.3 in a webview (takes some time to do it right). The idea behind it is, develop once deploy many. So it runs on Windows, Linux, Mac, Mobile etc.

Because it runs on many platform browsers I want to add text-ads to the bottom of the game that can show up everywhere. So when I settle the game on the web it must show ads and when it runs inside a specific platform executable (in a webview) it must also show ads WITHOUT the need to change anything. This must be done with in the same manner, develop once deploy many because it difficult enough to make all of cross-compatible.

**Ad Networks**

First, I did some research how to start. Then I found admob but to me it seems nearly to dead because there are allot of changes going on. They 'advice' me to use adSense for Mobile but man, that is a second business to run! Besides, both of these does not have support for javascript or PHP (to be able to implement an own interface to the ads).

Then I found mobfox. Got some mixed feelings about it. Cannot find any info of profits but does support a PHP API and got this working already. It seems that has bought the open source platform mAdserve - http://www.madserve.org/. Found also many many others but don't want to discuss my feelings about these here. To show you some list - http://gulyani.com/complete-list-of-mobile-ad-networks-companies/

But all these ad platforms seems to be only one device target in mind, mobile or not mobile, I want it all! I like to run a business but not a second business. The only thing I want is a banner on the bottom of the game, that's all.

**Ad bidding system (Vickrey auction)**

The second idea is to implement an Vickrey auction system (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey_auction) that advertisers can bid on placing there own ad inside the game. Google (in-app advertising) has also a solution for this but is java based so cannot use this. Because this seems very complicated to create myself (have seen some implementations) but want this to combine with the ads of another network with the same banner structure.

**Questions:**

I have still many questions about advertising and it is not easy were to start, what is a good choice to do. Maybe someone give me some advice or point me into the right direction. There are many many results when google on it, it is very difficult to choose because of the amounts of results. It is a big business.

- Is there a solid ad network that can be used in all kind of HTML pages, mobile, dekstop anywhere
- Is there a solid ad network that can handle the bidding system I described above?

The ad network must provide a Javascript API or PHP API for there services.

Any doubts what I want? Please let me know!

Comment: It is in the first line, with HML5/CSS3/Javascript

Comment: I mean have you used any tool like `construct 2 or gamesalad etc..` or frameworks like `cordova...`

Comment: No, just made own library to avoid bloat of a framework (functions I don't use). Made a simple javascript bridge for all kind of platforms that supports only vibrate and some required app events. But when it is not there it will not break the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest you to Use google adsense as they pay highest revenue and it has advertising option for both desktop and mobile websites. And when your game gains enough popularity just released the bidding systems as you can generate more revenue from targeted advertisement.

If you are thinking to go for other advertisers I don't suggest as they are unstable may use tricks like improper counting of hits. And adsense is powered by Google (who is not a fan of Google?) is stable trusted and highest paid site.  Even then you want to move to other advertisers just do a good research about their partners their history and paying criteria.

If you are thinking to use different advertiser for different versions... Or simply you cannot figure out how to use different code for desktop and  mobile. Use below code

```
function isMobile(){
    //if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)session_start();
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    //@link http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
    //Great regex :)
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
    return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

PS: most advertisers are against using two advertisers in same site to solve the problem get another domain for say mobile version sync the data. But I don't suggest the way.

Sources :
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/180195?hl=en

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en (in your case google suggest to use adsense for content)

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/17470

http://monetizepros.com/blog/2013/what-are-the-top-ad-networks-2013/

Personal experience :)

Comment: Hi Thanks, I take a look at it. One of the problems with adsense is that they need to access a mobile webpage to determine I'm following their guide and that I'm allowed to use their services. But it is not a mobile webpage! Also I must develop the whole thing first before I am able to show it. That's makes it very difficult to use.

Comment: It clearly says that same publisher id for mobile websites can be used as desktop (read the page you will understand) https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/68724?hl=en

Comment: "If you're looking to monetize a mobile site designed for users of iPhone, Android, or other high-end devices with browsers capable of executing Javascript, simply use any standard AdSense for content ad unit that fits your mobile-optimized site."

Comment: The problem with adSense is that Google want to verify the page (that must contain the ads) before I can use adSense. They want to check if the page is following the Google guidelines for adSense. This can take a week. But it is not a webpage, it is a webapp! How can I handle this?

Comment: Yes I agree that adsense verifies domain name age, content and many other things and if you are not able to generate content I don't suggest you going for textual ads as they are generated according to your website content and if they are not they may show arbitrary content even if category wise they are not relevant taking an example if you choose game as category you will lose customers(small website advertise small project, I believe) and if you don't chose game they will not be interested. So even if you get an textual ad company revenue will be low.

Comment: There are many other ways to generate revenue have a look http://www.boxuk.com/blog/monetizing-your-web-app-business-models/

Comment: Another trick I get on my mind is you can place YouTube video in your page and open it when user opens the page later monetize your video but again it will take time.

Comment: Here's is an article which will give you enough help if you still stick to your idea of showing ads http://techcrunch.com/2007/03/22/web-apps-101-your-three-point-success-plan/

Comment: @Erwinus if you have questions about AdSense, it makes more sense to ask Google.